# Kinect v2 does not work as webcam for tool but for libfreenect2

Tags: kinect, webcam, libfreenect2

I want to use my Kinect v2 as a webcam for some tools which requires a webcam as an input device as example cheese.
However, I am able to start protonect from libfreenect2 like described at the bottom of this page: https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/blob/master/README.md#linux

Protonect will display 4 streams, which is fine, but cheese and other tools tell me there is no device found. The same is true for different other tools I tested like VLC media player.

I read the different guide but most I found seems only to be true for Kinect v1.
According to the openkinect FAQ, the Kinect should be able to use as the webcam with a Kernel above 3.0. Mine is 4.10 while Ubuntu is 17.04 and I use an AMD GPU with newest Pro driver.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?